# PostgreSQL ODBC driver and cursor issue

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, odbc, database-cursor

In my app I use cursor to recieve dataset from stored procedure.
But I have an error:

```
ERROR:  invalid transaction termination
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at COMMIT
SQL state: 2D000
```

This error raise in case when AutoCommit option is not set.
In DBeaver IDE if autocommit is ON, I have no error.
In pgAdmin 4 this I have error any way (autocommit is on OR is OFF).

In my app I use ODBC driver to connect.
How can I set autocommit option in driver settings?

Test code bellow:

```
create table test_table (spid int);

insert into test_table
select 1;

insert into test_table
select pg_backend_pid();

do $$
    declare
        var_ImplicitResultSet refcursor := 'var_implicitresultset';
    begin
        delete from test_table where spid = pg_backend_pid();
        commit;
        open var_ImplicitResultSet FOR SELECT spid from test_table where spid <> pg_backend_pid();
    END
$$;
fetch all from var_implicitresultset;
```

Or is there another way to get the dataset from the stored procedure?
P.S. I'm adapting an old application so I need to learn how to return datasets from within procedures

Thanks for answer!

Comment: Maybe similar quetion https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249446/unable-to-create-commit-inside-postgresql-11-5-procedure

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/setting-the-commit-mode